# intellij 22021.2.2 grails app forge isn't showing any profiles

Tags: intellij-idea, grails

My Intellij idea ultimate v 2021.2.2 is not showing any profile list when creating a new grails project via the grails app forge option.

This renders the embedded builder to be useless - you cannot proceed as the drop down is empty, and nothing is selectable in the drop down.

I can however go to the grails v5 app forge site, and generate one from the site and then get the zip unpack it and import it into Intellij which works

what's wrong with my Intellij configuration and how do I fix it ?

Comment: "what's wrong with my Intellij configuration" - I don't think anything is wrong with your configuration. "how do I fix it ?" I am not sure.  See the following: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/12134 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-280782 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-280371

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue and found [youtrack issue IDEA-280782](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-280782) filed with JetBrains. I was able to download and install the early access (EAP) version 2021.3 Beta and it did fix the issue. You can visit the [IntelliJ Early Access Program](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/#section=windows) page to install the beta version with the fix.